# Вывод определенных объектов из массива

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Всем привет. У меня есть функция при нажатие на которую я хочу получать объекты из массива только первой категории. Она мне возвращает только один элемент. В чем ошибка?

```
takeCategory1() {
    this.categoryService.getCategory()
        .pipe(map((category): any => {
            for(let key of category){
                if(key.name.includes('Наименование услуги категории 1')){
                    return [key];
                }
            }
        }))
        .subscribe(category => {
          this.category = category
            console.log(category)
        })
  }
```

Вот как выглядит сам массив:

```
[
0: {id: 0, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 0"}
1: {id: 1, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 1"}
2: {id: 2, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 2"}
3: {id: 3, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 3"}
4: {id: 4, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 4"}
5: {id: 5, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 5"}
6: {id: 6, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 6"}
7: {id: 7, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 7"}
8: {id: 8, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 8"}
9: {id: 9, name: "Наименование услуги категории 1, строка 9"}
10: {id: 0, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 0"}
11: {id: 1, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 1"}
12: {id: 2, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 2"}
13: {id: 3, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 3"}
14: {id: 4, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 4"}
15: {id: 5, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 5"}
16: {id: 6, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 6"}
17: {id: 7, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 7"}
18: {id: 8, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 8"}
19: {id: 9, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 9"}
]
```

Comment: потому что значение потока маппится на `return[key]`, поэтому и получаете одно значение, и в колбеке `map` должно быть `categories`, а не `category`. rxjs map это не тоже самое что `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: @overthesanity, `flatMap` + `filter`?

Comment: @Grundy, нет, одного `map` достаточно, просто человек маппит значение неправильно, там достаточно біло бі `map((categories) => categories.filter(...))`

Comment: @overthesanity, а, да, иначе ему потом надо и результаты обратно собирать, но выглядело бы красивее :)

Comment: @Grundy `mergeMap` применим к потокам, а там он получает raw массив сразу, если бі нужно біло что-то "развернуть" так сказать из потока, то да, обічній `map` не уместен

Comment: @overthesanity, не, я про `flat` же говорил, что коллекцию из потока по элементам обходится, тогда к ней можно применить `filter` и останется только результат в массив собрать.

Comment: @Grundy `flatMap == mergeMap`, 2 года назад переименовали :D ті наверное `from` имеешь в виду, он коллекции обходит по єлементам, а `flatMap` параметром принимает фабрику возвращающую поток типа `flatMap(() => http.post(...)).subscribe(response => ...`

Comment: @overthesanity, да, похоже все перепуталось :-)

Comment: @overthesanity, точно помню видел пример где как раз на вход был массив массивов, а на выходе фильтровались по элементам каждого массива. Но не помню что там за функция была

Comment: @Grundy ну сейчас у них АПИ сильно отличается от того, что біло года 2 назад. если "флаттенить" массив, то сейчас єто `mergeAll`

Comment: @overthesanity, `flatMap` еще доступен, так что примеры не обязательно два года назад были :-)

Comment: @Grundy с rxjs >= 5.5 `flatMap` єто [алиас](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/9922c02) на `mergeMap`

Comment: @overthesanity, ага, я как раз это и имел ввиду, что в примерах могло оставаться `flatMap` почему я его и запомнил, но не обращал внимания, что это алиас на другую функцию

Comment: Всем спасибо, сам потупил немного и сделал вот так takeCategory1() {
    this.categoryService.getCategory()
        .pipe(map((category): any => {
            return category.filter(x => x.name.includes('Наименование услуги категории 1'))
        }))
        .subscribe(category => {
          this.category = category;
            console.log(category);
        })
  }

Answer (score -1):

Я бы вам рекомендовал сделать какой-нибудь признак категории внутри, если имя внезапно изменится, то вам придется править код (что не есть хорошо), к примеру `19: {id: 9, name: "Наименование услуги категории 2, строка 9", category:1}` и проверят по нему, и поскольку map является iterable (циклом если по простому) вы можете написать

`map((category): any => {
            return any.category == 1
        })`

Comment: ві как будто не читали комментарий, rxjs map это не тоже самое что Array.prototype.map

Comment: `any.category` - не будет работать, так как вот тут `(category): any` - это  **тип** параметра.

Comment: Я лишь хотел донести, что внутренний цикл не нужен

Comment: @bobanobi4, донести не получилось, плюс приведен кусок неработающего кода.